# How to apply styles using styled components

Tags: css, reactjs

I try to style my component using:

```css
export const StyleCascader = styled(Cascader)`
  background-color: gray;
  ul.ant-cascader-menu {
    background: red !important;
  }
`;
```

Here i am using styled components, but even i added `!important`, the styles don't appear. What could be the issue?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-trigger-ant-design-demo-gw0kb?file=/StyleCascader.js:74-210

Comment: @HermitCrab, could you take a look, please?

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned `ul.ant-cascader-menu` selector, but there is no such element in DOM.[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-trigger-ant-design-demo-f9gb5

Comment: please, open it, clicking on that gray background. I want to add backgroundColor to dropdown.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-trigger-ant-design-demo-f9gb5
here

Comment: why the styles don't appear without createGlobalsStyles?